# Bootstrap calendar not working properly in opencart

Tags: opencart

In my Opencart site, calendar is working properly in admin panel Sales Analytics map. I have used same code to show calendar at catalog, where it isn't working. What am I doing wrong?

I have given sample code to show calendar

```
<div class="pull-right">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i><i class="caret"></i>
    </a>
    <ul id="besttime" class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
        <li>
            <a href="week"><?php echo $text_week; ?></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="month"><?php echo $text_month; ?></a>
        </li>
        <li class="active">
            <a href="year"><?php echo $text_year; ?></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Please remove the "opc" tag on this StackOverflow question; your question is not related to it.

Comment: no console errors. simply bootstrap calendar not working in catalog

Comment: what code you using? provide us with some code or information so that we can see what the issue might be

Comment: i have edited my post... see that for code

Comment: Is the library for the bootstrap calendar loaded in the template where you want to achieve the bootstrap calendar ?